# Reinforcement Learning Program Freezes over time

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, freeze

I am currently working on a Reinforcement learning program that teaches itself how to play the game snake. The Issue I am facing is that as the program runs in the background, it slowly eats up more and more of the memory and ultimately, the program crashes. I made sure to check if there is any lists that slowly grow over time. As far as I know, there is no such lists as they become empty at the beginning of every iteration. I have added the training code below(Images of the code):

[Code part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oaOj.png)

[Code part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfHzv.png)

[Code part3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scW2I.png)

This is the first time I am posting a question in stackoverflow. Apologies if I have posted the question in a wrong manner.

Comment: Welcome! Get rid of the images showing the code and copy and paste the code text itself. This will make the code searchable and possibly help future users wih similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is the problem with the memory? If it is, try to set the variables outside the for loop and empty them for each loop.

```
A=[]
B=[]
history=[]
for iteration in range(iterations):
   A=[]
   B=[]
   history=[]
```

Can you try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: I found a different solution to the problem. The program runs smoothly for 200 iterations. So after 200 iterations, I saved the model and ran the program again by loading the same model. Since I can't turn on the program again and again, I used cmd prompt and used && to run the same program for around 200 times.